# Editing html templates

Tags: c#, html

I am going to create a function in my application that is going to send som status mails to several receivers in a list.

Earlier i used plane text format on the email, but now i want to send the mail based on som html templates. I need tips reguarding a good way to insert data into these templates before sending them.

eks

%CpuStatus%

%HardriveStatus%

and so on. I have the solution for everything except a way to fill anchors like that with data. This is a WinForm application so i dont have access to the ASP functionality

Comment: You can't just do `String.Replace("%CpuStatus%", value)`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this sort of thing would be the simplest?

```
// This would most likely be loaded from a file or database.
string emailBody = "CPU Status: %CpuStatus%\nHard Drive Status: %HardriveStatus%";

string cpuStatus = MyService.GetCpuStatus();

emailBody.Replace("%CpuStatus%", cpuStatus);
```

Comment: Im looking som somthing where you can edit the html template as an object. Where every anchors is somthing like a property. So you create the object based on the html file

Comment: Some people have managed to use Razor syntax (the engine behind MVC 3 views) to create a very flexible HTML template system.  Link: http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ There's some examples on the home page that show what a HTML template would look like and how you can set the template items using properties using the `PageModel` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to make a big project out of it, you can use a webbrowser control, load it with your html file and then use the WebBrowser's Document property to get an HtmlDocument object. You can then loop through it's children (recursively) to find the tags you want to change.

Personally, I would do the .Replace method suggested previously.